# How to replicate rails like migration behaviour using java libraries

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, database-migration, liquibase, flyway

Coming from rails platform I really admire how ROR handles database migrations.

For sake of context

1. We write migration files using a simple ruby dsl.
2. Execute `rails db:migrate` which migrates the database & updates a file `schema.rb`

`schema.rb` is a file which maintains final state of database all the time. 
It is quite useful in scenarios such as running integration tests in a `CI` or when a new developer joins your team and wants to setup his/her database quickly.

Since most of the migrations play around with the same set of tables, It's much faster and simpler to create a database directly from the final state of DB than running all the migrations again (for example Flyway migrations run sequentially in Java so if we have a v1 to v8, all will be applied each time in `CI` if it's running on a fresh image, whereas in Rails only the final stage maintained in `schema.rb` is applied)

Is there any java library which supports this out of the box? or with help of some simple scripts.